# What SystemColor is this?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

Please have a look at the image below:

[image]

what [SystemColor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx) has the panel in the red rectangle?

What `SystemColor` should be used in general for the background of a control that is presenting content? I tried `SystemColors.ControlBrush` and `SystemColors.ControlLightBrush` but none of them would match the color in the image. Is it possible that the color is redefined somewhere else?

Comment: It is not a system color.  You have visual styles enabled, the background color of a tab page is part of the theme.  You have a non-default theme selected.  WPF does theming its own way, you could perhaps use Winforms' VisualStyleRenderer.GetColor() but probably shouldnt.

Comment: @Hans Passant: you have an eagle eye ;) I do use XP style with silver color scheme, I tried `VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Tab.Pane.Normal).GetColor(ColorProperty.FillColor)` and `VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Tab.Body.Normal).GetColor(ColorProperty.FillColor)` but it would give me the same color as `SystemColors.Control`. I give up now and will simply use `SystemColors.Control`

Answer (score 3):

My guess is it's a gradient they're applying between SystemColors.  To me it looks lighter at the top and darker at the bottom.  Here is a link to the SystemColors by theme, maybe it will help:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think its just `Drawing.SystemColors.Control`

This seems to be the default for new controls, `Me.BackColor = Drawing.SystemColors.Control`

Edit: I think the area in question is Window
`Me.BackColor = Drawing.SystemColors.Window`

Comment: sorry but as I said in my question i tried `Drawing.SystemColors.Control` already it is much too dark, `Drawing.SystemColors.Window` OTOH is much too light...